# Hapi.js with Glue CORS headers not setting

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Okay, so this is what my glue manifest looks like. As you can see the cors object is being set but I keep getting this stupid error when running from frontend app: localhost:3000.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/api/v1/check_out_order' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

```
"glueManifest": { 
        "server": {         
            "port": 8082,
            "routes": {
                "cors": {
                    "origin": ["*"],
                    "additionalHeaders": ["cache-control", "x-requested-with"]
                }
            }
        },
```

anyone that may have a solution for me will be appreciated much! TIA!

Answer (score 0):

try this:    `var server= new Hapi.Server({ port: 8082, routes: { cors: true }});`

Comment: Thanks for your input Idriss and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's often helpful to others if you give a little context for your solution, so other people can understand the problem and how you solved it. That way they can hopefully work it out themselves next time!

Answer (score 0):

Your back-end **needs to accept also the 'OPTION' type of HTTP request** on all endpoints + add the header to all your responses.

> The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options
>   for the target resource. The client can specify a URL for the OPTIONS
>   method, or an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

> The Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header indicates whether the
>   response can be shared with requesting code from the given origin.

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin